# Ember and Zurb Foundation 5 on Heroku deployment does not recognize mobile device.

Tags: heroku, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I have a simple Ember app I've made to learn Ember and I deployed it to Heroku [here](http://ember-template.herokuapp.com/). When I view it on my desktop and resize the browser window it adjusts accordingly to its mobile view. However, when I look at it on my phone it only displays it as a normal desktop page.

Is this an issue with Ember, Heroku, or Foundation 5?

Comment: Just looking at your app using the chrome emulate your site show a phone view when emulating a phone. Your bug has nothing todo with heroku. I would try turn of Ember and make sure that Zurb is working correctly by emulating the a phone in chrome. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=de

Comment: Yeah I've tried the emulator before and it didnt work. I dont know how you expect me to "turn off Ember" when I need it to even make the app basically work. My nav is a partial included on all my templates and I need ember to display them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the head of your app.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I can see that you have it included in your app on github but in the browser that meta tag is not being displayed.

I have an ember app using foundation on heroku [here](http://ember-weather.herokuapp.com). It is working well on my phone. The code is [here](https://github.com/kiwiupover/ember-weather/blob/master/app/index.html#L8).

Cheers

Comment: Well crap. I thought I had pushed that to heroku. Ugh, its always the simple things. Thanks!